# Azure DevOps: how to install a windows feature which requires a restart?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, windows-server-2019

Azure DevOps: how to install a windows feature which requires a restart?

I need to install this:

Install-WindowsFeature WebDAV-Redirector

But it needs a restart, I dont think thats possible on a pipeline agent

I need it to start: Set-Service WebClient -StartupType Automatic

Comment: If it indeed need restart, what about using self host agent and then run pipeline based on it?

Comment: Yeah, I had hoped to do it without a selfhosted vm to save costs & maintenance etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you agreed, if you indeed need start up, the solution should be use self host agent and then run pipeline based on it.